# (websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial )Can this Dial only create one connection?

Tags: go, ws

https://github.com/jwwsjlm/KedouFollow
I wrote a simple small program. Its function is to follow the target tadpole
But I want to create N tadpoles and follow the target tadpoles together. I found the library github.com/gorilla/websocket and it seems that I can only create one ws link. If I call Dial multiple times, the program will get stuck.
I'm learning golang. I hope I can get some great help. Although my question is just a casual operation for you.
Below is the function I created by calling

https://github.com/jwwsjlm/KedouFollow/blob/main/ws/ws.go#L21

I hope to be able to create N tadpoles and then follow the goal. I have already completed one.

Comment: Can you check my code? It freezes when I link to the second one.